# problems with "sliding menus" program

Tags: javascript, menu

I was reading a program to make sliding menus. Though the program works fine,there are certain things for which i don't have a clue what do they mean and what are they doing.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shakespeare's Plays</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Shakespeare's Plays</h1>
<div>
    <a href="menu1.html" class="menuLink">Comedies</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
        <li><a href="pg1.html">All's Well That Ends Well</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg2.html">As You Like It</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="menu2.html" class="menuLink">Tragedies</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
        <li><a href="pg5.html">Anthony &amp; Cleopatra</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg6.html">Hamlet</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="menu3.html" class="menuLink">Histories</a>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu3">
        <li><a href="pg8.html">Henry IV, Part 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pg9.html">Henry IV, Part 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: white;
color: black;
}

div {
padding-bottom: 10px;
background-color: #6FF;
width: 220px;
}

ul.menu {
display: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 5px;
}

a.menuLink {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Java Script**

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
    if (allLinks[i].className.indexOf("menuLink") > -1) {
        allLinks[i].onclick = toggleMenu;
    }
}
}

function toggleMenu() {
var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
var thisMenuName = this.href.substring(startMenu,stopMenu);

var thisMenu = document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style;
if (thisMenu.display == "block")  {
    thisMenu.display = "none";
}
else {
    thisMenu.display = "block";
}

return false;
}
```

In the `javascript` code:

1. what do these 2 statements do ?

   ```
   var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
       var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
   ```
2. what does `this.href` mean . I know that `this` refers to the link but what does `href` denote ?
3. what does the statement `thisMenu.display == "block"` mean ? I mean to say what is `display` and what is `block` . The code does not declare it anywhere.
4. In the same way what is meant by `none` ?
5. What does the statement `document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style` return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> 1. what do these 2 statements do ?
>
> var startMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
>     var stopMenu = this.href.lastIndexOf(".");
> ```

That code is within the *toggleMenu* function that is assigned to an onclick listener of link elements (they are probably the items in your menu). When the function is called by the onclick handler, the function's *this* keyword is set to a reference to the element (i.e. the link). So the first line is getting the position of the last '/' in the href property, the second is getting the index of the last "." in the href.

> ```
> 2. what does this.href mean . I know that this refers to the link but
> ```
>
> what does href denote ?

It is a refernce to the link's href property, which is initially set to the value of the *href* attribute.

> ```
> 3. what does the statement thisMenu.display == "block" mean ? I mean
> ```
>
> to say what is display and what is block . The code does not declare
>   it anywhere.

It is changing the value of the display property of the element's style object to "block", which is one value that it may have according to the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display). A better strategy is to set the display property in CSS (or just use the default) and in code set it to "" (empty string) so that it adopts the default or cascaded style (which can be any one of 13 values and might be different in different browsers so setting it specifically can be an issue).

That way the layout and display are independent of the code, which just hides it or returns it to whatever it was.

> ```
> 4. In the same way what is meant by none ?
> ```

That makes the element not part of the document flow, effectively hiding it and meaning it doesn't have any effect on the document layout.

> ```
> 5. What does the statement document.getElementById(thisMenuName).style return ?
> ```

It returns a reference to the element's style object, it's used to make the code more concise (and likely a tad faster, not that you'd notice here).

Comment: so why i can't just write `this.lastIndexof("/")`

Comment: Read my answer to your first question and you can answer that your self. But just in case: *this* references the DOM element, it doesn't have a *lastIndexOf* property. It **does** have an *href* property whose value is a string, and strings **do** have a *lastIndexOf* property.